# Getting "Jdbc is not defined" when running a javascript piece of code

Tags: javascript, jdbc

I am trying to build a small app using javascript and a remote MySql database, and I have set up the above project in Visual Studio Code:
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pQ9G.png)

This piece of code works perfectly when I run it under Google Appscript:

```
var port = 3306;
var dbName = "sql7621994";
var username = "sql7621994";
var password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
var server = "sql7.freemysqlhosting.net";

function xsomareg() {
  try {
    var url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + server + ':' + port + '/' + dbName;
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
    var stmt = conn.createStatement();
    var guarda = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM registos");
    guarda.next();
    console.log(guarda.getDouble(1));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed with error: %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

THE PROBLEM:
When I run it under Visual Studio Code (in the  apps.js file) I get the message bellow:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYqoB.png)

Using SqlTools extension, I am able to run the SELECT statement is VSC and get the correct result:
[Select with sqltools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biUdd.png)

As I am new to this I’m probably missing something. Can someone please give a hand?
Many thanks.